# Is it possible to avoid the singularity problem of a 2nd order differential equations by restricting the solution range?

Tags: differential-equations, singularity

I would greatly appreciate your help in implementation of *Mathematica* for solving a 2nd order differential equation expressing some important engineering problem.

Apparently, this equation has no analytical solution. Therefore I attempt to solve it numerically with maximal possible approach to the analytical effect, while using the `ParametricNDSolve` command.

The equation has 3 variables: `n`, `Ω` and `ψ` and differentiation is by `z`. Actually, `z = 1`. n can be above zero and below it, however the values rarely exceed ±3. `Ω` and `ψ` are positive numbers and they can reach big values. As the 1st approach I have defined `n = 3`. The expression is:

```
Solution = ParametricNDSolve[{Ω f''[z] - f'[z] - ψ f[z]^n == 0,
                              f[0] - Ω f'[0] == 1,f'[1] == 0}, f, {z, 1, 1}, {Ω, ψ}];
```

Unfortunately *Mathematica* is unable restrict itself to `z = 1` and produces the singularity messages at `z < 1`.

My question is thus following: is it possible to restrict the solution to z=1 without attempting to solve at z<1?

Comment: Is it f''[z][z] or  f''[z]   or   z  f''[z] ??

Comment: it is f''[z], sorry for this typo

Comment: Because one boundary condition is at `z = 0` and the other at `z = 1`, `ParametricNDSolve` must integrate from `0` to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Because boundary conditions are specified at z = 0 and at z = 1, ParametricNDSolve must integrate between those two endpoints. However, this does not in general prevent obtaining a solution.

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Ω f''[z] - f'[z] - ψ f[z]^3 == 0, 
    f[0] - Ω f'[0] == 1, f'[1] == 0}, f, {z, 0, 1}, {Ω, ψ}];
```

which then can be evaluated at `s[Ω, ψ][1]`.  For instance,

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[s[Ω, ψ][1], {ψ, 5}]], {Ω, 1, 5}, AxesLabel -> {Ω, f}]
```

[image]

It is the case that stiffness is encountered at small `Ω` for `ψ == 5`.

**Addendum**

The parameter `ψ` can be eliminated by rescaling `f` by `ψ^(-1/(n - 1))`, which reduces parameter space from two to one dimensions.  With the rescaled `f` designated `g`,

```
t = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Ω g''[z] - g'[z] - g[z]^3 == 0, g[0] - Ω g'[0] == 1, 
    g'[1] == 0}, g, {z, 0, 1}, {Ω}]
Plot[t[Ω][1], {Ω, 1, 20}, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, All}, AxesLabel -> 
    {"Ω", "f \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(ψ\), FractionBox[\(1\), \(n - 1\)]]\)"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot! I have the following question: perhaps the singularity could be avoided or reduced by defining other solution method?

Comment: @SitraAhra   Although there probably are several ways to avoid this issue, I recommend the rescaling shown in the addendum above.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Indeed the rescaling solves the problem, for all positive values of Ω and n. Thank you a lot again!